# Simple function with pointers and references

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So I have a homework for my c++ classes. And (like everyone) I can't get my head around pointers and references in functions.

I am to create a funciton of prototype:

```
const double* avr(const double* arr, size_t size, double& average)
```

**Where:**

`arr` - is a pointer to a array declared in main function

`size` - is a size of an array

`average` - is a reference which should later be injected with a mean average from an array (`arr[]`)

The point of a function is to inject variable average with mean average of array elements and then return the pointer to the element of an array, which is the closest to this mean average

for example the program below:

```
double arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,7};
size_t size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
double average = 0;
const double* p = aver(arr, size, average);
cout << *p << " " << average << endl;
```

**should print:** 
4 3.66667

I don't want to take shortcuts, so I don't expect the answer.
However I do have some questions.

- Why is the function avr a pointer? What does it point to?
- Is there a way to transfer a mathematics of size to the function `avr`? What I mean is - I want to keep `main()` clean and have the size_t size math works kept in `avr()`. (obviously i can't change a prototype)
- how can I pass an mean average to a average reference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a regular c++ project you would not use a c style array (`double arr[]`) but `std::vector<double>` or `std::array<double,6>`. Those classes have a `size` method to get the number of elements. But if you have to use a c style array, then you would need to pass the size of that array yourself.

Comment: Your question states what the return value from the function is - a pointer to the element of the array `arr` that is closest to the computed average.   The function could equally return a `size_t` which represents an index, so `arr[index]` is the element closest to the computed average.  After all, `(&arr[i] - &arr[0]) == i` for any value of `i` between `0` and `size-1`  (where `size`, as you have computed it, is the number of elements in `arr`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the function `avr` a pointer? What does it point to?

This function returns a pointer to constant float, It returns a pointer to the nearest number to average, But why it is pointer? I can see no reason, Maybe it just has educational purpose, I think there is no need to use pointer and pointers should be avoided as much as possible, Here returning by value would be better.

> Is there a way to transfer a mathematics of size to the function `avr`?

No you can't, Your function get a pointer to your array, The compiler doesn't know what the pointer is pointing to and it means it does not now what it contains, or how many elements it has. So you need to calculate the size outside and pass it to function as you did.

> how can I pass an mean average to a average reference?

Not clear what you are asking here, but here is an explanation that might help you understand pass by reference: Consider you have a function like `void func (int &param)`, Here when you call this method it internally will declare an `int reference` named `param` just like you can do outside, and then it will be a reference to you given parameter, As you know reference is an **alias** to given parameter, So you just pass your variable (for example you have `int x;` just call `func (x);`) and then in the function buddy `param` would be the alias of `x` and be used.

Keep that in mind when you are passing your parameter by reference, any change to that parameter will affect your original passed one (they are the same, Alias, Remember?), So if you want to keep yourself to not accidentally change the parameter which you don't want to change, change your function to get it as `constant reference` like this `void func (int const &param);`